# Is my proof correct? Infinite rational numbers

Tags: solution-verification

**Question**

Prove that between any two points a and b ($a\not=b$) on the x-axis there
are infinitely many rational points.

**My Proof**

Lemma 1.
Between any 2 rational numbers there exist infinite rational numbers.

Let $b\ge a$ multiply $a$ and $b$ by $10^n$ where $p$ is the smallest integer such that $(b\times10^p)-(a\times10^p)\gt10$. Let $m=\lceil a\times10^p\rceil$ and $n=\lfloor a\times10^p\rfloor$. From this we get $a\le \frac{m}{10^p}\lt\frac{n}{10^p}\le b$. As $m$ and $n$ are both rational be are done

Comment: Is this supposed to be a proof of the lemma, or is the lemma something you alreday have at your disposal? (Also, you *could* zbe a bit less wasteful and multiply only with some $N$ such that $N(b-a)>2$)

Comment: You still need to show that there are two distinct rationals between any two numbers. And if you know how to show this, then the conclusion doesn't require your lemma - just recursive application of the above fact. Even one rational is enough.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen , would this be better?

Let $b\ge a$ multiply $a$ and $b$ by $p$ where $p$ is the smallest integer such that $p(b-a)\gt2$. Let $m=\lceil a\times p\rceil$ and $n=\lfloor b\times p\rfloor$. From this we get $a\le m \lt n \le b$ and we are done